# mounting a network location to a windows docker container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to mount a network location of this type \host\folder to a windows docker container.
I found few solutions out there but none seems to work:

This following one works on linux containers but not on windows one:

```
services:
  myservice:
    volumes:
      - NetworkLocation: c:/app/MountedLocation
volumes:
  NetworkLocation:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      device: "\\host\folder"
      o: username=username,password=pw,rw
```

I also found this, that is described as the correct way for windows containers:

```
services:
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: //host/folder
      target: c:/app/MountedLocation
```

In this case I get an error from docker saying that //host/folde is an invalid mount path, mount path must be absolute.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, windows primarily uses server message block, or SMB. If you take a look at [`driver_opts`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver_opts) documentation, you can derive it from there:

```
volumes:
  example:
    driver_opts:
      type: "smb"
      o: "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/docker/example"
```

Comment: about "driver_opt" all the documentation says is "Specify a list of options as key-value pairs to pass to the driver for this volume. Those options are driver-dependent - consult the driver's documentation for more information. Optional." It is not easy to find out what options are needed for a windows share to be mounted on windows container. The example you provide does not work.

Comment: Actually it seems that options are not even supported for windows containers: I get the error "options are not supported on this platform"